# Tem como fazer um código em PHP, que ao fazer o upload das imagens, hospede as mesmas no servidor do blogger

Tags: php, servidor

Tenho um código php que faz o upload de múltiplas imagens ao mesmo tempo e hospeda ela no meu próprio servidor, só que eu gostaria de deixar o servidor mais "leve" hospedando as imagens em servidores free como o blogger. Existe algum meio de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a API do Flickr para isso:

https://www.flickr.com/services/developer

Link do API quanto ao Upload de imagens:

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html

**Upload**

URL utilizada para o upload das imagens/fotos:

> https://up.flickr.com/services/upload/

**Autenticação**

Este método exige autenticação com permissão 'write' (gravação).

**Parâmetros (argumentos)**

1. photo
       O arquivo para upload.
2. title (opcional)
       O título da foto.
3. description (opcional)
       Uma descrição da foto. Pode conter algum HTML limitado.
4. tags (opcional)
       Uma lista de tags separadas por espaços para aplicar à foto. is_public, is_friend, is_family (opcional)
       Definir como 0 para não e 1 para sim. Especifica quem pode visualizar a foto.
5. safety_level (opcional)
       Definir 1 para Seguro, 2 para Moderado, ou 3 para Restrito.
6. content_type (opcional)
       Definir 1 para Foto, 2 para Captura de tela, ou 3 para Outro
7. hidden (opcional)
       Definir 1 para mostrar as fotos em todos os resultados de busca, 2 para não mostrar nas buscas públicas.

**Resposta**

```
<photoid>1234</photoid>
```

**Possíveis erros**

- 2: No photo specified
     The photo required argument was missing.
- 3: General upload failure
     The file was not correctly uploaded.
- 4: Filesize was zero
     The file was zero bytes in length.
- 5: Filetype was not recognised
     The file was not of a recognised image format.
- 6: User exceeded upload limit
     The calling user has reached their monthly bandwidth limit.
- 95: SSL is required
     SSL is required to access the Flickr API.
- 96: Invalid signature
     The passed signature was invalid.
- 97: Missing signature
     The call required signing but no signature was sent.
- 98: Login failed / Invalid auth token
     The login details or auth token passed were invalid.
- 99: User not logged in / Insufficient permissions
     The method requires user authentication but the user was not logged in, or the authenticated method call did not have the required
  permissions.
- 100: Invalid API Key
     The API key passed was not valid or has expired.
- 105: Service currently unavailable
     The requested service is temporarily unavailable.
- 106: Write operation failed
     The requested operation failed due to a temporary issue.
- 116: Bad URL found
     One or more arguments contained a URL that has been used for abuse on Flickr.

**Alternativas**

ImageShack: https://imageshack.us/ (API: http://api.imageshack.us/)

Picasa Web Albums Data API: https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol